# Rails load slow query in "each" loop via ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a query executed as part of an each loop which is particularly expensive so I'm wanting to load it after the rest of the page load, ideally with some sort of spinner to indicate activity, but that's not really the main concern. I'm able to load a basic partial after page load however doing it within an each loop has me stumped!

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @rates.each do |rate| %> 
...
<%= payment(rate.rate, @loan_amount, @payment_freq, 30).round(0) %> #expensive query
...
<% end %>
```

**helper that does the calculation**

```
def payment(rate, bal, freq, term) 
  formula  = ((rate / 100 / freq) * bal) / (1 - ((1 + (rate / 100 / freq)) ** (-term * freq))) 
end
```

Edit - I've moved the calculation to it's own partial however am still wanting this partial to load after the rest of the page.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @rates.each do |rate| %> 
...
<tr id="payment-<%= rate.id %>"></tr>
...
<% end %>
```

**index.js**

```
$(function () {
  $('#payment-1').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "payment", :locals => { :rate => @rates } ) %>");
});
```

**partial**

```
<% @rates.each do |rate| %>
  <%= payment(rate.rate, @loan_amount, @payment_freq, 30).round(0) %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I have now is that the partial is inserting all of the calculated values in the same table row as the js is hard-coded to go to 'payment-1' and I'm unsure how to make this dynamic.

Comment: what is the problem elaborate in details ?

Comment: I want to use ajax to populate the expensive part of my each loop after the rest of the page loads and I don't know how.

Comment: means your code work fine but you wants that some write the code of ajax related for you.Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, I need help on the ajax part. Thanks!

Comment: so why are you doing it with ajax if you wants to move code on other file then you can create another partial and can call with the required locals.

Comment: I've moved the expensive query to it's own partial but still want to load this after the rest of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this now and it turns out to be fairly straightforward, although there are a number of pieces involved.

**index.html.erb**

This sets up an empty div which I then populate with the results of the ajax call. It also includes a spinner which I remove when I populate the div.

```
<p id="payment-<%= rate.id %>"></p><div id="spinner-<%= rate.id %>" class="spinner"><%= image_tag("images/loader.gif") %></div></td>
```

**Ajax call**

This is where most of the magic happens. It fires once the rest of the page has loaded and calls a new template which returns a json response. When it returns data I then remove the spinner and populate the new data into the correct div.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "home-loans/payment.json?deposit_amount=<%= params[:deposit_amount] %>&purchase_price=<%= params[:purchase_price] %>&freq=<%= params[:freq] %>",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      $('#spinner-'+data[i].rate).hide();
      $('#payment-'+data[i].rate).append(data[i].payment);
    }
  }
```

});

**payment.json.erb**

This generates the json to return to the ajax call. You'll want to use a json validator to make sure you're returning valid json, but it's fairly straightforward.

```
[
<% @rates.each do |rate| %>
{"rate": "<%= rate.id %>",
"payment": "$<%= payment(rate.rate, @loan_amount, @payment_freq, 30).round(0) %> <%= params[:freq] %>"}<% unless rate == @rates.last %>,<% end %>
<% end %>
]
```

**Route**

Just ensures that the ajax call hits the right controller action.

```
match 'home-loans/payment' => 'homeloans#payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach I would consider

1) put a hidden form on the page with a hidden field which contains the id of the next rate to be populated.

2) bind a javascript function to both ajax success and document ready. This function submits the above form if the rate id in the hidden field is valid.

3) your .js partial which fills in the rate information also fills in this hidden field with the next rate ID required or makes it invalid when the last rate is sent, and adds teh data by adding an element not populating the same one.

The idea is that when the document is ready and on each subsequent successful ajax request another ajax request is sent to populate the next rate.